# Set focus in Popup's Listbox in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight-4.0

I am working in Silverlight. In my Silverlight Application there is One Textbox and One Popup with Listbox.
When i Write any text in Textbox then my popup is open But i want to extend one more thing when i press Down Arrow Key that time i want to set focus in listbox item.
I have also try many thing and still i not getting any solution.
I also try this

```
int selectedIndex = lstRoot.SelectedIndex;
lstRoot.SelectedIndex = 0;
lstRoot.Focus();
lstRoot.SelectedIndex = selectedIndex;
```

Still focus is not set in lstRoot.

Please help me....!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ScrollViewer for scrolling Item and In Popup add Listbox for display items and you can easily set focus on listbox's item.
for eg.

```
lstRoot.Focus();
```

It through set focus on current scrolled item and easily up and down in listbox item.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
    lstRoot.SelectedItem = modelItem;
    lstRoot.Focus();
```

Comment: Thanks Dipak,
I have try this but it does not set focus to listview.

Comment: is your popup getting focus at first place when you open it?